# Dusty Environment - Fan Alternative

Tags: fan, cooling, overheating, heatsink

I manage several desktop computers in dusty environments.  We frequently must clean out the cases to ensure adequate ventilation.

Is there such a thing as reliable, fanless cooling for an off-the-shelf, brand-name desktop computer?

Comment: have you considered placing an air filter near the computer air intakes to pre-filter the air?

Comment: Even a fanless system requires airflow and as such will accumulate quite a lot of dust.

Comment: [You might consider a PC enclosure](https://startpage.com/do/search?query=pc+dust+enclosure&cat=web&pl=chrome&language=english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there's just too much heat in general purpose desktop PCs, except in machines designed and manufactured to be fanless from the get go ([example](http://www.tinygreenpc.com/), [example](http://www.atlastsolutions.com/fanless-thin-mini-itx-pc-core-i7-haswell-8gb-120gb-ssd-asus-q87t/)).

As some point the heat needs to be dissipated. Even water-cooling requires fans to cool the radiator(s).

Put filters on your intakes ([example](http://www.startech.com/ca/Computer-Parts/Fans/High-Flow-Mesh-Air-Filter-for-12cm-Fans~FANFILTER12M), [example](http://www.amazon.ca/Computer-Air-Filter-Polyurethane-Protects/dp/B000FJU8BC)), or move the computers to a less dusty environment and extend the cabling for keyboards, mice, monitors etc. into the dusty environment.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider a fanless PC. There are some nice options these days. search amazon for ideas.

Comment: Good answer, just not as complete

Comment: I've switched to using fanless computers here on our plant floor.  Absolutely no issues with them being completely covered up with rags/dirt/whatever.  They aren't cheap, but just keep running.